# ajax how to pass a dom element to ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making an ajax call that I want to modify a select box based on the results.  The problem I'm having is that the dom element doesn't have scope inside of the ajax call so I can't find its siblings and modify them with the data.  To clarify look at the html below

```
<div class="field_group">
    <select name="example1">
        <option value="something">something</option>
    </select>

    <select name="example2">
        <option value="something">something</option>
    </select>

</div>
```

Basically when example 1 changes I modify example 2's data.  It is important to note that under no circumstances can I use some sort of direct selector to get around my problem because all fields on this page are dynamically selected and there could be from 0 to 1000 of them.  Below is my actual code

```
$(".landscape_type").on('change',function(){
var my_landscape_type = $(this);
console.log($(this).val());
var product_category = $(this).val();
$.post('/quotes/ajax_get_quote_products/'+product_category, function(data,my_landscape_type) {
        var data_object = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data_object);
        console.log('should output here');
        console.log(my_landscape_type.val());
        if(data_object["error"]) {
            alert(data_object["error"]);
            my_landscape_type.parents('.field_group').children(".landscape_product").empty();
            my_landscape_type.parents('.field_group').children(".landscape_product").append("<option selected='selected' value='-1'>No Products Found!</option>");
        } else {
            my_landscape_type.parents('.field_group').children(".landscape_product").empty();
            my_landscape_type.parents('.field_group').children(".landscape_product").append("<option selected='selected' value='-1'>Select a Product...</option>");
            for (index in data_object) {
                my_landscape_type.parents('.field_group').children(".landscape_product").append("<option value='"+data_object[index]["product_id"]+"'>"+data_object[index]["product_name"]+"</option>");
                console.log(data_object[index], index);
            }
        }
  });
});
```

If you look below the line that says should output here you can see where I should be getting the value of my_landscape_type, but since I don't get it it has lost scope and passing it the way I am doesn't work.

Comment: Try removing `my_landscape_type` from your callback function arguments

Comment: Didn't think it would be that simple, but it turns out it was...Thank You

Comment: Glad to help. I posted an answer with an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable does have scope, the thing is you are overwriting it with the argument from the `$.post` callback function, so remove it from the argument list and you should be fine.

`.post` callback parameters:

```
success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many of these fields, perhaps you could give them IDs and pass the appropriate one with your AJAX call. Then do what you need to do with it, and return the ID of what needs to get updated in your callback. Then you could do something like

```
var val = $('.landscape_type#'+id).val();
```

Comment: In this particular case that would prove cumbersome because a user can add and remove fields from the form, but I get what you are saying